# Getting the error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java

```
public class DebugThree1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double myCheck = 50.00;
        double yourCheck = 19.95;
        System.out.println("Tips are")
        calcTip(myCheck);
        calcTip(yourCheck);
    }

    public static int calcTip(double bill)
    {
        final double RATE = 0.15;
        final double tip = bill * RATE;
        System.out.println("The tip should be at least " + tip);
        return tip;
    }
}
```

I am trying to calculate a waiters tip at 15% of the bill.
When I run the compiler, i get the error message: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int return tip;

Comment: Why _are_ you returning an `int`?

Comment: Your `calcTip` method is declared to return an `int`, but you're returning a `double` (and ignoring it in `main`).

Comment: Sorry I am relatively new to java. I had to fix multiple errors on this code but this last bit gave me some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the return statement of method from `int` to `double` like this:

```
   public static double calcTip(double bill){
```

Because when using `int` like a return type you loss the precision.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're returning an "int" if you want to return an int try typecasting the double for "tip"

Ex:

final double tip = bill * RATE;

int i = (int) tip;

return i;